# Finding limit point

Tags: real-analysis

How to find limit point of the set {sin(1/n)+cos(1/n) where n belongs to the set of natural numbers}?

I tried the solution by putting values of n and then finding the points whose nbd has infinitely many points of the set

Is this correct way to find the limit point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin (1/n)=0$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\cos (1/n)=1$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}(\sin (1/n)+\cos (1/n))=1$$
$$\implies (\forall \epsilon>0) \;\;\; (\exists N>0) \;\;:\; $$
$$\sin (1/N)+\cos (1/N)\in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon) $$

thus, $1$ is a limit point.